# Open mbox File?

Tags: email, mbox

How to open a **mbox file**? Mutt displays no mails when calling `mutt -f sent.mbox`.

The mbox format is "From" without colon.

Is there any mbox viewer for Linux?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Mutt should be able to open an mbox file. It's normal to have a `From` line without a colon at the top: this is for the email's envelope. It's difficult to diagnose your problem without seeing the file contents. Of course I appreciate the file contents is probably too private to publish. Look at the file as a text file (for example with `less`). Is the `From` line followed by header lines (`From:`, `Subject:` and so on)? Is there a `Lines:` header, a `Content-Length:` header?

Comment: It looks like this: http://pastebin.com/49fG0N7E I deleted the recipient, content and domain name.

Comment: how about alpine?  It was called pine before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line of the mail is the “envelope From line”. It begins with the 5 characters `From␣` where `␣` is a space character. This is normal.

```
From Christian xxx <cg@xxx> Mon May  15 20:22:35 2010
```

What is unusual is that the email address is between `<…>`. This is unusual. I don't know if it's against the RFCs or not, but I can see Mutt chokes on it.

You should get a valid mailbox (as in, one that Mutt can parse) by processing the mailbox file through the `formail` command from [procmail](http://packages.ubuntu.com/procmail) [image: Install procmail].

```
formail -ds sed '1 s/^From .* <\(.*\)>/From \1/' <sent.mbox >sent-reformatted.mbox
mutt -f sent-reformatted.mbox
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Unfortunately, formail doesn't add this header. RFC 822 / 4155 knows nothing about it.

Comment: After reformatting the file with formail, four (of a hundred) mails are displayed in mutt.

Comment: @chris How many files does `formail -ds sh -c 'cat >$FILENO.mail'` create? Can mutt read them as individual mailboxes containing a single mail?

Comment: 606 files are generated. But Mutt doesn't read them.

Comment: @chris Damn. Again, this is difficult to diagnose without seeing a mail. Can you take one of these single-mail files and edit out all private data, check that mutt still can't open it, and post it here?

Comment: this is a simple mail without mime-multiparts: http://pastebin.com/2aQFgxe2 It contains German umlauts. Do they make trouble?

Comment: I deleted the umlauts. Even so, the mail isn't displayed.

Comment: @chris Ok, I've reproduced this and found the problem: Mutt doesn't like it when the envelope `From` line isn't of the form `From something@somewhere trailer text`. In particular, it ignores a line where the envelope from address is `John Doe <add@ress>`. Now I'm going to see how to fix this.

Comment: @chris I don't know whether it's a bug in mutt or in the program that produced this mailbox, but see my answer for a fix.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll clean the mbox files up with your script.

Answer (score 7):

In thunderbird you can open the file by placing it in thunderbirds local profile folder, under `$HOME/.thunderbird/<profilename>.default/Mail/Local Folders/` An .mbox file there will be picked up by Thunderbird and displayed. See also [the detailed instructions](https://commons.lbl.gov/display/~jwelcher@lbl.gov/Reading+an+mbox+file+with+Thunderbird) linked by prashanth in a different comment.

Comment: This is the best answer. I was able to view all my 100K messages downloaded from GMail backup this way. Thanks.

Comment: Tested as of Thunderbird 102.13.0 Ubuntu 23.04, I can't find out how to create a profile without actually logging into some email account, it seems to check no matter what I try (linked post mentions this is a required step, but was able to avoid actual linkup with a dummy account). Annoying.

Answer (score 4):

[Any text editor](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/mbox) is capable of opening `.mbox`. Besides text editors Mozilla Thunderbird can open them too.

Comment: Do I have to copy the file to the Thunderbird profile? I don't want to change it.

Comment: Yes. I was able to open mbox file in Thunderbird. This link provided the steps to be followed. https://commons.lbl.gov/display/~jwelcher@lbl.gov/Reading+an+mbox+file+with+Thunderbird

Comment: @prashanth 's link is a working solution. I could download my gmail archive as an `.mbox` file (https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) and open it with Thunderbird. All you have to do is place the `.mbox`-file in the _Local Folder_ path on your file system. Before that you must create at least a newsgroup account with your real email adress (write anything as the news server address, it doesn't matter). Restart Thunderbird and then you have a new folder with all your mails and attachements.

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of nightmare on Windows with Firefox, where the .mbox gets open but only the first message is available, I found that Evolution works well: I created a new folder and then from File\Import... (I'm from Italy, the menu it's actually Importa...) I was able to read that old messages...

Comment: I dislike that by opening the mbox file, its really importing the file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to view an `mbox` file in Thunderbird, I needed the following:

- add the [Import/Export](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) extension, otherwise the "import" option in the Tools menu did not give me the option to import a *file* (only data, etc., from another account/app); and
- to use an account which was configured for POP, not IMAP (since the import into IMAP is not possible -- at least with the `mbox` file I was importing).

With those two conditions in place, everything worked well, and the file was available "as mail" in Thunderbird after import (with attachments intact).

Comment: All the import/export extension does is copy the mbox file to thunderbird's local profile folder. You can also do that manually.